# Генератор пароля с условием

Tags: python

Все привет! помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачку:
Хочу написать функцию которая будет возвращать пароль длина которого зависит от числа которого ему передадим, если ничего не передать то любое от 6 до 100, так же в пароле обязательно должны быть цифры, заглавные и прописные буквы (хотелось бы +- пропорционально)
написал такое, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли это дело как-то оптимизировать?

```
def generated_password(num=random.randint(6, 100)):
    pas = ''
    for x in range(num//3):
        pas = pas + random.choice(string.digits)
    for x in range(num//3):
        pas = pas + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    for x in range(num - num//3 - num//3):
        pas = pas + random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return pas
```

Comment: А в пароле есть требование "сначала цифры, потом большие буквы, потом маленькие и количество символов из разных групп должно быть примерно одинаковым"? Если нет. то почему он делается именно так?

Comment: а вы пробовали искать похожие вопросы на сайте?

Comment: Чем меньше условий на пароль, тем он разнообразнее, тем труднее его подобрать. Условия, которые вы привели, предназначены для человека, придумывающего пароль. Люди любят придумывать простые пароли, им нужны эти правила. Машине дают алфавит и число символов, она генерирует сложный пароль без всяких правил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так переписать:

```
import random
import string

def generate_password(num = random.randint(6, 100)):
    num_digits = num // 3
    num_uppercase = num // 3
    num_lowercase = num - num_digits - num_uppercase

    digits = random.choices(string.digits, k=num_digits)
    uppercase_letters = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=num_uppercase)
    lowercase_letters = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=num_lowercase)

    password = ''.join(digits + uppercase_letters + lowercase_letters)
    return password

print(generate_password())
print(generate_password(99))

# Бонусом можно добавить перемешивание символов в пароле
password = generate_password(99)
password_list = list(password)
random.shuffle(password_list)
shuffled_password = ''.join(password_list)
print(shuffled_password)
```

Вывод:

```
2651657183629XSFQUWGPUDOMIbkdqlbwqyezbz
691347980135530421398568592938646RRRRADQZIWYHYYOHQYJKFTVSRKSFCFICWvmcdrqmpgxstotcjognmzyfcjebjkfyhx
20A1p6c7WK43Ki9e4574NWFP15Ep6ilCSzzgUFhc58CwsLCvT2HM8NZV69XIC2kO6jya6RkJFXpJ8a14iew0My8015vycjcbzY2
```